# How to call a method from an HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap how looks like that:

```
     hmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    // All list of exercises
    hmap.put("ArrayVerrification", new ArrayVerification());
    hmap.put("DivideNumber", new DivideNumber());
    hmap.put("Hello", new Hello());
    hmap.put("Rectangle", new Rectangle());
    hmap.put("StringOperations", new StringOperations());
    hmap.put("Substring", new Substring());
    hmap.put("SumOfPrimeNumbers", new SumOfPrimeNumbers());
    hmap.put("Test", new Test());

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> pair : hmap.entrySet()){
         if(pair.getKey().equals(extractClassNameFromComand)) {
              // this I want to do something like that
              // eg : Hello hello = new Hello;
              //      hello.run();
        }
    }
```

Every object have a method called "run". I want to call that method but i don't know how to do that. Can you help me, pls? :)

Comment: Do you have `HashMap<String, Runnable>`?

Comment: Yes I try, but I receive an error at : hmap.put("ArrayVerrification", new ArrayVerification()); I think the syntax must be different.

Comment: `hmap.get("Rectangle").run()`?

Comment: Do all your classes implement runnable?

Comment: @Alexandra What error do you get? How have you declared the map? It would help if you provided a [mcve], possibly with only one or two of those classes.

Comment: @Alexandra an error is meant to be **read**. If we only have a few lines of code, without context, and you choose to hide the error from us, we can't possibly help.

Comment: I tried to improve my example. Sorry..

Comment: You contradict yourself. Your map in the code uses Object, not Runnable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the classes have a no-arg method called `run()`, then make all the classes implement [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), and then declare `Map` value to be a `Runnable`:

```
Map<String, Runnable> hmap = new HashMap<>();
// code to fill map here

for (Map.Entry<String, Runnable> pair : hmap.entrySet()){
    if (pair.getKey().equals(extractClassNameFromComand)) {
        pair.getValue().run();
    }
}
```

If you want to defer the construction of the object until inside the loop, use a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html):

```
Map<String, Supplier<Runnable>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
hmap.put("ArrayVerrification", ArrayVerification::new);
hmap.put("DivideNumber", DivideNumber::new);
hmap.put("Hello", Hello::new);
hmap.put("Rectangle", Rectangle::new);
hmap.put("StringOperations", StringOperations::new);
hmap.put("Substring", Substring::new);
hmap.put("SumOfPrimeNumbers", SumOfPrimeNumbers::new);
hmap.put("Test", Test::new);

for (Map.Entry<String, Supplier<Runnable>> pair : hmap.entrySet()){
    if (pair.getKey().equals(extractClassNameFromComand)) {
        Supplier<Runnable> supplier = pair.getValue();
        Runnable obj = supplier.get(); // calls: new Xxx()
        obj.run();
    }
}
```